# Overcome duplicated methods static reference on super

Tags: java, inheritance

We all know that in Java, if you declare a `static` method in a `Abstract` class, that method will belong to the `Abstract` class, and not to its child. (There is no `abstract static`)

I have a simple database system that has a `Abstract` Model class:

```
public abstract class Model<T> {

     // WON'T WORK (unfortunately I can't use abstract static)
     public static T find(int id) {
          ...
     }

}
```

As you can see, I can't create a static method on that class that returns a generic, since that method is not inherited, so it belongs to the abstract class.

A workaround is to make a protected method on the abstract class and then a static method on each of its children:

```
public abstract class Model<T> {

     protected T find(int id) {
          ...
     }

}

public class User extends Model {

     public static User find(int id) {
           User dummy = new User();
           return (User) dummy.find(id);
     }
}
```

I feel that there are better ways of doing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not make a class which is being inherited by the abstract class, and which contains the method ?

Comment: The `find` method is always the same. Why should I repeat it on every inherited class?

Comment: Re-read my comment. create a Super class, which is being inherited by your abstract class, and that contains that method.

Comment: Isn't that what I just did with my example!?

Comment: @Stultuske You cannot inherit static methods from your (abstract) parent, and OP wants static methods.

Comment: yes, caught on a bit late. (monday morning blues :/).
Mauricio Giordano: why does it have to be static ?

Comment: @Stultuske If I want to "find" a `User` on my database, it doesn't make sense to need an instance of a `User` class (therefore, a `User`) to find another `User`.

Comment: looking to find a user doesn't really belong there (imo). Calling operations on a User like 'find, edit, ... ' should not be in 'User' rather in a 'UserHandler'. That might also solve the issue.

Comment: That would solve the problem indeed. The idea is to avoid creating those `dummy` classes that would look the same for all inherited classes. Too bad that Java doesn't allow `abstract static`... bad language design =/

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible options, although one is a bit of a hack. The first one would be to make `Model<T>` a normal class and adding a static method to get the model like this:

```
//I do not know how you want to do the user class, I just made it take the models class
private static final Model<User> MODEL = new Model<User>(User.class);
public static Model<User> model() {
    return MODEL;
}
```

You would use it like this: `User.model().find(id)`

Another option would be to add a public static variable to the class and `static` importing that variable to invoke methods on it as if it were the class and not the `Model` instance. For example:

```
public class User {
    public static Model<User> User = new Model<User>(User.class);
}
```

Importing it using `static import my.package.User.User;` would allow you to use `User user = User.find(id);` where the first `User` is the class name and the second `User` is the static variable.

Otherwise, you will have to put the static methods in each class, because unfortunately you cannot inherit or override them.

Comment: The first one is the most elegant way I think, thank you for the suggestion. The second one is to hacky.

Comment: The only problem with the first solution is that methods like `save` would be available (and it shouldn't).

Comment: Making those methods `protected` and letting the `User` class extend `Model` should work, although it might need some changes to `Model`.

Comment: Unfortunately no. If I have a real instance of `User`, I won't be able to use `user.save()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static generic method with a type that extends the parent class.  You will, however, need an instance of the type in order to do the return of type T.  The easiest way is to pass in the caller, but it could just be an empty instance.

For example, you can do the following:

```
//No more generic Model
public abstract class Model
{
    //Our generic static method; we need caller to get something of type T to return.
    public static <T extends Model> T find(int id, T caller)
    {
        ...
        return caller.getMyReturnObject(id);
    }
}
```

To invoke this you would just do

```
Model model = find(someId, new Model{...})
```

where `new Model{...}` can be replaced by `this` if you invoke it within a class that is a child of `Model`.

If you need to create a new instance of T in the method, then you will still need to pass in something as T (the caller still works) and use reflection to create the new instance (using something like `(T) type.getClass().newInstance();` instead of `new T()`).

Comment: Maybe `find(int id, Class<T> clazz)`, so to call would be `find(1, User.class)`? I can use `clazz.newInstance()` inside the method.

Comment: That would work much better if there isn't an instance available.